# Неверное кодирование при считывании .pb файлах

Tags: python, unicode, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, tensorflow

Я скачал код с github(Ссылка: https://github.com/llSourcell/deep_dream_challenge).
Эта программа видоизменяет картинку(deep_dream) . Для работы этой программы , нужно скачать zip файл(https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception5h.zip) и поместить его в папку data. Программа и папка с zip - файлом должны находиться в одной папке.

После запуска программы , появляется ошибка:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 2176-2177: surrogates not allowed
```

Из ошибки видно , что программа не может считать символы в позиции : 2176-2177 .

Какие есть варианты , как можно подправить кот , что бы он работал?

Вот код из гитхаба:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
from functools import partial
import PIL.Image
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import urllib.request
import os
import zipfile

def main():
    print("ok1")
    #Step 1 - download google's pre-trained neural network
    url = """https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception5h.zip"""
    data_dir = """data/"""
    print("ok1")
    model_name = os.path.split(url)[-1]
    local_zip_file = os.path.join(data_dir, model_name)
    print("ok1")
    if not os.path.exists(local_zip_file):
        print("ok1")
        # Download
        model_url = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        with open(local_zip_file, 'wb') as output:
            output.write(model_url.read())
        # Extract
        with zipfile.ZipFile(local_zip_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
            zip_ref.extractall(data_dir)
    print("ok1")
    # start with a gray image with a little noise
    img_noise = np.random.uniform(size=(224,224,3)) + 100.0
    print("ok1")
    model_fn = 'tensorflow_inception_graph.pb'
    print("ok1")
    #Step 2 - Creating Tensorflow session and loading the model
    graph = tf.Graph()
    print("ok2")
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession(graph=graph)
    print("ok3")
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile(os.path.join(data_dir, model_fn), 'rb') as f:
        print("ok3")
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        print("ok3")

        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

        print("ok3")
    t_input = tf.placeholder(np.float32, name='input') # define the input tensor
    print("ok3")
    imagenet_mean = 117.0
    print("ok3")
    t_preprocessed = tf.expand_dims(t_input-imagenet_mean, 0)
    print("ok3")
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, {'input':t_preprocessed})
    print("ok3")

    layers = [op.name for op in graph.get_operations() if op.type=='Conv2D' and 'import/' in op.name]
    feature_nums = [int(graph.get_tensor_by_name(name+':0').get_shape()[-1]) for name in layers]
    print("ok3")
    print('Number of layers', len(layers))
    print('Total number of feature channels:', sum(feature_nums))


    # Helper functions for TF Graph visualization
    #pylint: disable=unused-variable
    def strip_consts(graph_def, max_const_size=32):
        """Strip large constant values from graph_def."""
        strip_def = tf.GraphDef()
        for n0 in graph_def.node:
            n = strip_def.node.add() #pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
            n.MergeFrom(n0)
            if n.op == 'Const':
                tensor = n.attr['value'].tensor
                size = len(tensor.tensor_content)
                if size > max_const_size:
                    tensor.tensor_content = "<stripped %d bytes>"%size
        return strip_def

    def rename_nodes(graph_def, rename_func):
        res_def = tf.GraphDef()
        for n0 in graph_def.node:
            n = res_def.node.add() #pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
            n.MergeFrom(n0)
            n.name = rename_func(n.name)
            for i, s in enumerate(n.input):
                n.input[i] = rename_func(s) if s[0]!='^' else '^'+rename_func(s[1:])
        return res_def

    def showarray(a):
        a = np.uint8(np.clip(a, 0, 1)*255)
        plt.imshow(a)
        plt.show()

    def visstd(a, s=0.1):
        '''Normalize the image range for visualization'''
        return (a-a.mean())/max(a.std(), 1e-4)*s + 0.5

    def T(layer):
        '''Helper for getting layer output tensor'''
        return graph.get_tensor_by_name("import/%s:0"%layer)

    def render_naive(t_obj, img0=img_noise, iter_n=20, step=1.0):
        t_score = tf.reduce_mean(t_obj) # defining the optimization objective
        t_grad = tf.gradients(t_score, t_input)[0] # behold the power of automatic differentiation!

        img = img0.copy()
        for _ in range(iter_n):
            g, _ = sess.run([t_grad, t_score], {t_input:img})
            # normalizing the gradient, so the same step size should work 
            g /= g.std()+1e-8         # for different layers and networks
            img += g*step
        showarray(visstd(img))

    def tffunc(*argtypes):
        '''Helper that transforms TF-graph generating function into a regular one.
        See "resize" function below.
        '''
        placeholders = list(map(tf.placeholder, argtypes))
        def wrap(f):
            out = f(*placeholders)
            def wrapper(*args, **kw):
                return out.eval(dict(zip(placeholders, args)), session=kw.get('session'))
            return wrapper
        return wrap

    def resize(img, size):
        img = tf.expand_dims(img, 0)
        return tf.image.resize_bilinear(img, size)[0,:,:,:]
    resize = tffunc(np.float32, np.int32)(resize)

    def calc_grad_tiled(img, t_grad, tile_size=512):
        '''Compute the value of tensor t_grad over the image in a tiled way.
        Random shifts are applied to the image to blur tile boundaries over 
        multiple iterations.'''
        sz = tile_size
        h, w = img.shape[:2]
        sx, sy = np.random.randint(sz, size=2)
        img_shift = np.roll(np.roll(img, sx, 1), sy, 0)
        grad = np.zeros_like(img)
        for y in range(0, max(h-sz//2, sz),sz):
            for x in range(0, max(w-sz//2, sz),sz):
                sub = img_shift[y:y+sz,x:x+sz]
                g = sess.run(t_grad, {t_input:sub})
                grad[y:y+sz,x:x+sz] = g
        return np.roll(np.roll(grad, -sx, 1), -sy, 0)    

    #BACK TO CODE IN THE VIDEO###########################################################################################
    ########################################################################################################
    ##############################################################################

    #CHALLENGE - Write a function that outputs a deep dream video
    #def render_deepdreamvideo():


    def render_deepdream(t_obj, img0=img_noise,
                         iter_n=10, step=1.5, octave_n=4, octave_scale=1.4):
        t_score = tf.reduce_mean(t_obj) # defining the optimization objective
        t_grad = tf.gradients(t_score, t_input)[0] # behold the power of automatic differentiation!

        # split the image into a number of octaves
        img = img0
        octaves = []
        for _ in range(octave_n-1):
            hw = img.shape[:2]
            lo = resize(img, np.int32(np.float32(hw)/octave_scale))
            hi = img-resize(lo, hw)
            img = lo
            octaves.append(hi)

        # generate details octave by octave
        for octave in range(octave_n):
            if octave>0:
                hi = octaves[-octave]
                img = resize(img, hi.shape[:2])+hi
            for _ in range(iter_n):
                g = calc_grad_tiled(img, t_grad)
                img += g*(step / (np.abs(g).mean()+1e-7))

            #this will usually be like 3 or 4 octaves
            #Step 5 output deep dream image via matplotlib
            showarray(img/255.0)



    #Step 3 - Pick a layer to enhance our image
    layer = 'mixed4d_3x3_bottleneck_pre_relu'
    channel = 139 # picking some feature channel to visualize

    #open image
    img0 = PIL.Image.open('camer.png')
    img0 = np.float32(img0)

    #Step 4 - Apply gradient ascent to that layer
    render_deepdream(tf.square(T('mixed4c')), img0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

P.S.Если вы скопируете код из репозитория гитхаб, скорее всего он у вас не заработает , так как папка data должна находиться непонятно где , из-за этого лучше скопировать мой код , который работает по инструкции сверху.

P.S.S. UPDATE. После выполнения строки : graph.ParseFromString( f. read()) *Появляется ошибка...*

Comment: неплохо было бы указать какая строка кода выдает ошибку...

Comment: @MaxU graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read()) . На этой строке появляется ошибка.

Comment: `...папка data должна находиться непонятно где...` по тому коду из гитхаба, папка будет на уровень выше от папки в которой был скрипт запущен. Интересно, что у меня работает тот код.

Comment: Попробую с таким раскладом сделать...

Comment: @gil9red А вы создавали папку и скачивали файл , или программа сама это сделала?

Comment: Просто у меня после переноса папки дата на уровень выше , все равно точно такая же ошибка вылазит .

Comment: @True-hacker, дело не в папке, т.е. ошибка у вас обозначает что скрипт смог из той папки найти и считать файл модели ('tensorflow_inception_graph.pb'). Тот код немного переделал, он у меня работает: https://pastebin.com/8cqLAN4g . Но, думаю, у вас такая же ошибка будет. Я бы попробовал tensorflow переустановить

Comment: @gil9red Да , это так , теперь всё работает!Спасибо огромное. Можете пожалуйста этот комментарий в виде  ответа представить .

Comment: Т.е. вам помогла переустановка tensorflow?

Comment: @gil9red Да , после переустановки tensorflow программа заработала !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Автору помогла переустановка `tensorflow`. Возможно, версия `tensorflow`, которая у него стояла имела ошибку, которая была исправлена в последней версии.

Установка (или обновление):

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

аналогично для версии  с поддержкой GPU:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```